# Facing ImportError: DLL load failed while implementing Microsoft azure iothub_service_client

Tags: python, c++, node.js, azure, dll

I am trying to develop a python console application that implement IoT using Microsoft azure. For this purpose, I am following [very basic tutorial made for python developers by Microsoft azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-getstarted) in my ***Windows 10*** machine. Pre-installed [Visual C++ redistributable package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145) is one of the most important requirement to allow the use of native DLLs from Python among 4 prerequisites described into the Introduction section of the tutorial.

***My system configurations:***

```
Software                               Version
-------------------------------------------------------
Python:                                3.5.2
Visual C++ redistributable package:    2010, 2013, 2017
Node:                                  6.10.2
```

***Figure of Visual C++ redistributable package:***
[image]

***Problems:***

1. Visual C++ redistributable package is not installed since [Visual C++ redistributable package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145) in the tutorial is an older version (**2015**) then mine (**2017**).
2. It shows following error:

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "CreateDeviceIdentity.py", line 2, in <module>
       import iothub_service_client
     File "F:\Settings\Windows\ProgramFiles\Python\lib\site-packages\iothub_service_client\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
       from .iothub_service_client import *
   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
   ```

***Question:***

1. How how can I solve this problem?

**N.B:** I have completed those basic tutorial provided for **Java** and **NodeJS** developers.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue successfully, and I made the code `import iothub_service_client` works after installed [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145). So please install the 2015 version on your machine to resolve it, as the tutorial said,

> If you are using Windows OS, then [Visual C++ redistributable package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145) to allow the use of native DLLs from Python.

The link in the tutorial is for the 2015 verison.

Comment: The problem above mentioned is not solved by your suggestion / answer. Anyway I solved this by `upgrading the python version from 3.5.2 to 3.6.1`

Comment: The problem I ran into is I already have a newer version of the Visual C++ redistributable package installed, and that particular installer won't allow me to install the older version if the newer version is already installed.  On Python 3.7.3 and using azure-iothub-device-client==1.4.6 I still get the same error as above.